# Android - How to access a Fragment from a FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, android-fragmentactivity

I always get a `NullPointerException` when I try to access a fragment from inside my main activity. No matter what I do.

The issue is that I use `TabsPagerAdapter` and `ViewPager` and I don't know how to get the inflated views (the fragment's `onCreate()` method returns the inflated view already).

The goal is to get access to an element inside the fragment and hide or show it dynamically by a single background thread which should also do this for more fragments.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener
{
/* swipe view */
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

// tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Basic", "Advanced", "Settings"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* init swipe views */
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    /* addTab returns void, how to geht my fragements and their views???*/
    for (String tabName : tabs)
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this));

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
}

public void testFunction()
{
    FragmentPage1 fragmentPage1 = (FragmentPage1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_page1);
    GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) fragmentPage1.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.adBannerBasicLayout);
    gridlayout.setVisibility(GridLayout.VISIBLE); /* THATS MY GOAL */
}
```

**FragmentPage1.java**

```
public class FragmentPage1 extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);


        /* HERE IT IS WORKING FINE, 
        but later I want to make it visible again 
        from code OUTSIDE FragmentPage1 ??? */

        GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adBannerBasicLayout);
        gridlayout.setVisibility(GridLayout.GONE);

        return rootView;
    }    


    /* so I tried this, but also get always NullPointerException */
    public View getRootView()
    {
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_page1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="12"
        android:columnCount="5"
        >

        <!-- Some Banner Ads I want to hide show -->           
        <!-- I want to access this from everywhere! --> 
        <GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adBannerBasicLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adBannerBasic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                >
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                />

        </GridLayout>

        <!-- more stuff... -->
  </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me out, I'm totally stuck!

THANKS!

EDIT:

The scond line in testFunction() throws the NullPointerException:

```
 GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) fragmentPage1.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.adBannerBasicLayout);
```

because `getSupportFragmentManager()` always returns null:

```
FragmentPage1 fragmentPage1 = (FragmentPage1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_page1);
```

**Logcat Outoput**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.tzapp.smote.MainActivity.testFuntion(MainActivity.java:393)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At which line you are getting NullPointerException ? Show us stackTrace

Comment: Please post your logcat error output.

Comment: where´s the line when you´re adding the fragment to the activity?

Comment: I've added logcat output.

Comment: The scond line in testFunction() throws the NullPointerException.

`GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) fragmentPage1.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.adBannerBasicLayout);`  
fragmentPage1 is always null...

Comment: The fragments are added somehow here `for (String tabName : tabs)
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this));` There is no other place where the Fragments are explicitely used. The whole magic is done somehow by actionBar :( ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I found another answer, which is I think most satisfying :)

I forgot to mention that there is another class. It all comes from that stupid piece of example code for Swipe Views which is avaible somewhere on developers.google.com ...

Everytime I tried to access the FragmentPages via my TabPagerAdapter class using the stupid getItem(int i) method, I created a new Fragment() :-/ Very irritating!

**Class TabsPagerAdapter from bad google example**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {    

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity mainActivity){
        super(fm);
    }

    // page index, fragment selector
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: return new FragmentPage1(); // bad practice
            case 1: return new FragmentPage2(); // why should one do that?
            case 2: return new FragmentPage3(); 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

What a piece of crap ^^ And I just copied it over and then totally forgot about it's existence ;)

Moved instanciation of fragments to constructor and keeped them for later use. Works perfectly now.

**Class TabsPagerAdapter after optimization**

```
    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // hosted fragments
    private FragmentPage fragmentPageBasic;
    private FragmentPage fragmentPageAdvanced;
    private FragmentPage fragmentPageSettings;

    //constructor
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity mainActivity){
        super(fm);

        fragmentPageBasic = new FragmentPage();
        fragmentPageBasic.setMainActivity(mainActivity);
        fragmentPageBasic.setLayoutResource(R.layout.fragment_page1);
        fragmentPageBasic.setAdBannerResource(R.id.adBannerBasic);
        fragmentPageBasic.setAdBannerLayoutResource(R.id.adBannerBasicLayout);

        fragmentPageAdvanced = new FragmentPage();
        fragmentPageAdvanced.setMainActivity(mainActivity);
        fragmentPageAdvanced.setLayoutResource(R.layout.fragment_page2);
        fragmentPageAdvanced.setAdBannerResource(R.id.adBannerAdvanced);
        fragmentPageAdvanced.setAdBannerLayoutResource(R.id.adBannerAdvancedLayout);

        fragmentPageSettings = new FragmentSettingsPage();
        fragmentPageSettings.setMainActivity(mainActivity);
        fragmentPageSettings.setLayoutResource(R.layout.fragment_page3);
        fragmentPageSettings.setAdBannerResource(R.id.adBannerSettings);
        fragmentPageSettings.setAdBannerLayoutResource(R.id.adBannerSettingsLayout);
    }

    // page index, fragment selector
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: return fragmentPageBasic;
            case 1: return fragmentPageAdvanced;
            case 2: return fragmentPageSettings;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    // GETTERS
    public FragmentPage getFragmentPageBasic() {return fragmentPageBasic;}
    public FragmentPage getFragmentPageAdvanced() {return fragmentPageAdvanced;}
    public FragmentPage getFragmentPageSettings() {return fragmentPageSettings;}

}
```

Instead of having redundant FragmentPage1, Fragment2, FragmentPage3 classes, of course now there is only FragmentPage and FragmentSettingsPage (extends FragmentPage to override OnCreateView method), which results in a much cleaner and more understandable code.

**Class FragmentPage**

```
public class FragmentPage extends Fragment {

    protected MainActivity mainActivity;

    // layout resource
    protected int layoutResource;

    // view
    protected View rootView;

    //Admob
    protected AdView adBanner;
    protected int adBannerResource;
    protected int adBannerLayoutResource;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        onCreate(inflater, container);

        return rootView;
    }

    // manage common onCreate things
    protected void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container)
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, container, false);

        // admob banner
        adBanner = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(adBannerResource);
        adBanner.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                newAdBannerRequest();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                newAdBannerRequest();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            }
        });

        if(mainActivity.showAdBanners())
        {
            newAdBannerRequest();
            showAdBanner();
        }
        else
            hideAdBanner();
    }


    // ADMOB
    public void newAdBannerRequest()
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
                .build();
        adBanner.loadAd(request);
    }

    public void showAdBanner()
    {
        GridLayout adBannerLayout = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(adBannerLayoutResource);
        if(adBannerLayout.getVisibility() == GridLayout.GONE)
            adBannerLayout.setVisibility(GridLayout.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideAdBanner()
    {
        GridLayout adBannerLayout = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(adBannerLayoutResource);
        if(adBannerLayout.getVisibility() == GridLayout.VISIBLE)
            adBannerLayout.setVisibility(GridLayout.GONE);
    }


    // GETTERS
    public AdView getAdBanner() { return adBanner;}
    public View getRootView() { return rootView;}


    // SETTERS
    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {this.mainActivity = mainActivity;}
    public void setLayoutResource(int layoutResource){this.layoutResource = layoutResource;}
    public void setAdBannerResource(int adBannerResource){this.adBannerResource = adBannerResource;}
    public void setAdBannerLayoutResource(int adBannerLayoutResource){this.adBannerLayoutResource = adBannerLayoutResource;}
}
```

**Class FragmentSettingsPage**

```
public class FragmentSettingsPage extends FragmentPage {

    // Preferences
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(inflater, container);

        SharedPreferences preferences = mainActivity.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        // do some other top secret stuff here ;)


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Any ideas how to improve this further ?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong static value from the auto generated R file!

Instead of using *R.layout.fragment_page1* which references the XML resource you should use *R.id.fragment_page1* which should be the id of the fragment in your *R.layout.activity_main* XML file at /res/layout/activity_main.xml

- *R.layout* references XML layout files
- *R.id* references individual XML nodes (Views, Fragments etc.)

So in short, change:

```
FragmentPage1 fragmentPage1 = (FragmentPage1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_page1);
```

To:

```
FragmentPage1 fragmentPage1 = (FragmentPage1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_page1);
```

And make sure that your fragment id in /res/layout/activity_main.xml is set to *R.id.fragment_page1* like so:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.yourpackage.FragmentPage1"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_page1"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you use getSupportFragmentManager() to get fragment. 
Please double check if your FragmentPage1 extends a android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
not a 
android.Fragment;

Comment: I use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and tried also `public class FragmentPage1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Use **`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`** instead `import android.app.Fragment`

Please add this in your gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

Edit : please use **findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_page1) instead R.layout**

```
FragmentPage1 fragmentPage1 = (FragmentPage1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_page1);
```

Comment: Inlcuded `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'` to apps build.gradle file. But still same error.

Comment: Update your sdk & repository please

Answer (score 0):

After updating SDK and repository, there is new trouble. I cant build anymore and I dont want to compile on level 23 :(

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library
:app:prepareComInstabugLibraryInstabugcore161Library
:app:prepareComInstabugLibraryInstabugsupport161Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package org.tzapp.smote -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\SSMote\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 40.157 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
```

Comment: So, many hours later, now I'm finally compiling with SDK level 23 now ^^  But that didnt solve the problem... Unfortunately the NullPointerException had nothing to do with SDK or repository. But after aligning my whole code to Lv 23, I finally found the bad piece of code in my app that was causing the issue :)